# Converting date/time in sql to string

Tags: t-sql, datetime, varchar

Is there any way that I can convert the DateTime SQL value of this:

```
2011-10-11 00:00:00.000
```

to a string formatted exactly the same?

```
'2011-10-11 00:00:00.000'
```

I tried doing `cast(fl_from_dt as varchar(50)` but it converts it to something readable - ex. `'Oct 11 2011 12:00AM'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using SqlServer?

Take a look at the `style` parameter of `CONVERT()` here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx - in particular have a look at the *ODBC canonical (with milliseconds)* format.

For short you should use `style` 121 in the `CONVERT()` command.

> Style: 121
>
> ODBC canonical (with milliseconds) default for time, date, datetime2, and datetimeoffset
>
> yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm(24h)

Comment: Thanks! Wasnt even aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one !

```
select  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 112) 
+ right('0'+cast(datepart(hh, GETDATE()) as varchar(2)),2)
+ right('0'+cast(datepart(mi, GETDATE()) as varchar(2)),2)
+ right('0'+cast(datepart(ss, GETDATE()) as varchar(2)),2) as 'DateTime_STR2'
```